# ejabberd Oauth2 MQTT

Tags: oauth-2.0, mqtt, ejabberd

I am using MQTT with ejabberd.  I am also using a service to get an OAuth token.  Does ejabberd support the ability to for the MQTT module to have a callback module for authentication?  I want to pass the token in the options on the mqtt connection - I am assuming - and have the callback module call my identity provide to authenticate the token.